# SSRS grouping on multiple tablix

Tags: reporting-services

I have main report that has around 10 tablix and one sub report that  has 2 charts. I want the each tablix grouped by same column, but every table uses different datasets. By using List control, we can group the tablix and set a page break between each group. For that, list dataset  and tablix dataset must use the same dataset name.But I am not sure how to do that for multiple datasets. Could anyone please help me how to group multiple tablix based on same field value.Is it possible using list to do that? TIA
Attached for reference
 [image: Please find my attached part of tablix]. Each tablix uses different data sets.but the  field names are same.If Service_line column has 10 rows, then I want to display in 10 pages(one page per service line).If I select page break at each tablix, first tablix splits by that field name,after that next tablix starts to split by that field name. I want to show  A/R,cash,Adjustments in one page per service_line field and then next page the same tables but different service_line. So I thought Put in List all tables together and grouping at List level will solve the problem.Could you please help me on that? or if you have any other suggestions please let me know. I am not sure how to get this done. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm having a bit hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve. But to me it feels like this is a data problem. Would it work for your solution that you combine your datasets inside the SQL queries / views and have 1 column that will separate your data into different sets?

But I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to use that List Control for?

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Please see my edited question again and let me know your thoughts

Comment: Just to recap lets say you have 3 service lines (A, B and C). Your report would look like this. Page 1 would contain A/R, Cash and Adjustments for service line A, page 2 would contain A/R, Cash and Adjustments for service line B and so page 3 would contain same details for service line C?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you want to do is modify your data a little and use nested grouping.

Combine your datasets into one dataset using unions and label each row with column 'Category'that has value ('A/R', 'Cash', 'Adjustments')

for example your dataset might look something like this

```
CATEGORY    | SERVICE_LINE | Total  | ...
-------------------------------------
A/R         | A            | 100
A/R         | B            | 10
A/R         | C            | 1000
Cash        | B            | 50
Adjustments | B            | 100
Cash        | A            | 5
Cash        | C            | 400
Adjustments | C            | -100
Adjustments | A            | 9999
```

after that you will create a 1 tablix (forget about the lists). And inside that tablix you will create a row group for Category and merge all columns and set value for the cell as [CATEGORY]. Also for this row group you want to set Page Break options as "Between each instance of a group". After that create a row below that contains all the column labels Service_line, Total, etc.

Now what you have to do is create one more row group as Adjacent Below and use Service_Line as group by attribute.

with some UI tweaking you can get it to look as you want.

[image]

Comment: Excellent explanation, Thank you for the good answer. But unfortunately it may not work for me . Dataset itself is complex and  using mulitple union. Apart from that this report has some charts and small tables using 10 stored procedures . If I combine all those It will cause lot of performance issue. Is that possible combine datasets in SSRS?

Comment: Well simple but pretty annoying to maintain solution is to just create 3 separate rectangle items and inside their properties check the "Add page break after" and inside the rectangles create separate tables like you had done inside your question. This way you can separate the tables on different pages but the drawback is that you will have to maintain all the tables separately.